# How can overwrite an event from JS file in custom theme or module without overwriting the whole file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, mini-cart

How can overwrite an event from sidebar.js in my custom theme or custom module without effecting anything else that is located in the file? What is the best approach? I need to make the following change:

The file and event that I need to overwrite:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js
```

Change from:

```
         /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            confirm({
                content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                actions: {
                
                /** @inheritdoc */
                confirm: function () {
                    self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                },

                /** @inheritdoc */
                always: function (e) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

To:

```
     /**
     * @param {jQuery.Event} event
     */
    events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
    };
```

I just want to change this single element. Can you advise on the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use mixin**. Mixin is a class whose methods are added to, or mixed in, with another class.

A base class includes the methods from a mixin instead of inheriting from it. This allows you to add to or augment the behavior of the base class by adding different mixins to it.

**Click here for more**-> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar': {
                'Vendorename_ModuleName/js/sidebar': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> Create **sidebar.js** at **app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js**

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: @Greg - Can I see your final working code - because I was not able to use mixins for particular - events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] - thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way

Create requirejs-config.js
Something like this app/code/{Namespace}/{Theme}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar.js': '{Namespace}_{Module}/js/sidebar.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Then download sidebar.js and upload to {Namespace}_{Module}/web/js/ and make your changes

Happy coding

Comment: Why are people downvoting this approach yet not giving an answer? He obviously needs to override the constructor only using a preference - if this is not possible then this is the correct approach.

Comment: @gazZz this does not answer the question - "without effecting anything else that is located in the file". This answer will affect everything else in the file. If this is the only possible way then the answer should specify that. I imagine a mixin can be used here though

Comment: @BenCrook - Please help me to get this done using mixins - I will love to learn please because I was not able to achieve using mixins.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to create an example sorry, but you'll need to create a mixin like Msquare mentoins and overwrite the _initContent method, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html should help too

Answer (score -3):

copy file in app/desing/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/js/sidebar.js and change in your theme

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Will that overwrite the whole file? This is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: yes, unfortunately the whole file will have to be overwritten, maybe this article can help you https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#extend_js